# Set default login path in ssh config

Tags: ssh

I use the following config in my ssh config file:

```
Host host1
  Hostname host1
  User root 
  ForwardAgent yes 
  Port 22 
  ProxyCommand ssh -q user@host2 nc %h %p
```

Is there  a way to jump to a specific path when I connect using `ssh host1`?

I need this for shortening my rsync commands. For example instead of typing:

`rsync dir1 host1:/var/www/dir0/dir1/`

I want to type:

`rsync dir1 host1`

Answer (score 1):

As you seem to have root access to the remote box, you can add another user with the appropriate rights and a home directory at exactly that place.

This way you can leave out the path, because it's the home directory and you don't have to work as root.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done to my knowledge in the ssh config file. However, if you `ssh` into host1 and edit root's `.bashrc` file, you can accomplish the same thing.

```
[root@host1] $ echo "cd /var/www/dir0/dir1/" >> ~root/.bashrc
```

Then `exit` and `ssh` back in to verify it works for you.